# Recursive CTE with both child and parent links

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

Hi I have a table that stores the mappings of my data, e.g.

```
Data                  Map
id | letter | type    l | r
------------------    -----
 1 |   AA   | HEAD    5 | 1
 2 |   BB   | HEAD    2 | 1
 3 |   CC   | HEAD    6 | 2
 4 |   DD   | HEAD    3 | 2
 5 |  END-1 |  END    7 | 3
 6 |  END-2 |  END    8 | 4
 7 |  END-3 |  END
 8 |  END-4 |  END
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4eccfe/5

I want to find out all the END type links from a given source, e.g. for AA, I get END-1, END-2, END-3; for BB, I get END-1, END-2, END-3; for CC, I get END-1, END-2, END-3; for DD, I get END-4

I have written what I want using recursive CTE:

```
;WITH data(id, letter, type) AS (
    SELECT '1', 'AA', 'HEAD' UNION SELECT '2', 'BB', 'HEAD' UNION SELECT '3', 'CC', 'HEAD' UNION
    SELECT '4', 'DD', 'HEAD' UNION SELECT '5', 'END-1', 'END' UNION SELECT '6', 'END-2', 'END' UNION
    SELECT '7', 'END-3', 'END' UNION SELECT '8', 'END-4', 'END'
), map (l, r) AS (
    SELECT '5', '1' UNION SELECT '2', '1' UNION
    SELECT '6', '2' UNION SELECT '3', '2' UNION
    SELECT '7', '3' UNION SELECT '8', '4'
), my_list (origin, source, target, target_type, sid, tid, level) AS (
    SELECT s.letter, s.letter, t.letter, t.type, s.id, t.id, 0
    FROM data s JOIN map ON (s.id = l OR s.id = r)
    JOIN data t ON (t.id = l OR t.id = r)
    WHERE t.id <> s.id AND s.type <> 'END'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT my_list.origin, s.letter, t.letter, t.type, s.id, t.id, level + 1
    FROM data s JOIN map ON (s.id = l OR s.id = r)
    JOIN data t ON (t.id = l OR t.id = r) JOIN my_list ON s.id = my_list.tid
    WHERE t.id <> s.id AND s.type <> 'END' AND t.id <> my_list.sid
)
SELECT * FROM my_list
WHERE origin = 'BB' AND target_type = 'END'
ORDER BY level
GO
```

But the performance is not really good (on my real tables). Then I realise it is the ORs in the join conditions that are causing the issue, then I tried using UNION

```
my_list (origin, source, target, target_type, sid, tid, level) AS (
    SELECT s.letter, s.letter, t.letter, t.type, s.id, t.id, 0
    FROM data s JOIN map ON s.id = l JOIN data t ON t.id = r
    WHERE s.type <> 'END'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT s.letter, s.letter, t.letter, t.type, s.id, t.id, 0
    FROM data s JOIN map ON s.id = r JOIN data t ON t.id = l
    WHERE s.type <> 'END'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT my_list.origin, s.letter, t.letter, t.type, s.id, t.id, level + 1
    FROM data s JOIN map ON (s.id = l OR s.id = r)
    JOIN data t ON (t.id = l OR t.id = r) JOIN my_list ON s.id = my_list.tid
    WHERE t.id <> s.id AND s.type <> 'END' AND t.id <> my_list.sid
)
```

The difference is huge (on my real tables, the time is halved). For the above examples, I got

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 6, logical reads 100
```

vs

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 5, logical reads 75
```

But then when I tried to do the same for the recursive part, e.g.

```
my_list (origin, source, target, target_type, sid, tid, level) AS (
    SELECT s.letter, s.letter, t.letter, t.type, s.id, t.id, 0
    FROM data s JOIN map ON s.id = l JOIN data t ON t.id = r
    WHERE s.type <> 'END'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT s.letter, s.letter, t.letter, t.type, s.id, t.id, 0
    FROM data s JOIN map ON s.id = r JOIN data t ON t.id = l
    WHERE s.type <> 'END'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT my_list.origin, s.letter, t.letter, t.type, s.id, t.id, level + 1
    FROM data s JOIN map ON s.id = l
    JOIN data t ON t.id = r JOIN my_list ON s.id = my_list.tid
    WHERE s.type <> 'END' AND t.id <> my_list.sid
    UNION ALL
    SELECT my_list.origin, s.letter, t.letter, t.type, s.id, t.id, level + 1
    FROM data s JOIN map ON s.id = r
    JOIN data t ON t.id = l JOIN my_list ON s.id = my_list.tid
    WHERE s.type <> 'END' AND t.id <> my_list.sid
)
```

the result becomes slower (on my real tables, 5 times slower).

I wonder why is it slower and if there is other way to get rid of the ORs to speed up the query? Database is MS SQL SERVER 2008R2

Thank you

Comment: Do you really need the or/union construction? Can't you start from one end and move in one direction so to speak= I.e. `select distinct m1.r from map m1 left join map m2 on m1.r = m2.l where m2.l is null`

Comment: I won't mind if single direction can get what I want

Comment: I don't think you can completely get rid of the `OR`s, but this can be simplified, potentially.  One important question - your example data set is distinct in `map` with ids that represent `'END'` rows - is this true of your actual data?

Comment: Also, they're all on the left... does this hold true as well?  I'm curious, because that somewhat implies your relationships aren't bi-directional.

Comment: Yes, END nodes all on left, only HEAD nodes can be on both left and right (e.g. 'BB')

Answer (score 1):

I might have gotten this wrong, but can't you push the predicate:

```
WHERE origin = 'BB'
```

inside the CTE. I.e.:

```
;WITH my_list (origin, source, target, target_type, sid, tid, level) AS (
SELECT s.letter, s.letter, t.letter, t.type, s.id, t.id, 0
FROM data s 
    JOIN map 
        ON s.id = l 
    JOIN data t 
        ON t.id = r
WHERE s.letter = 'BB'
UNION ALL
SELECT s.letter, s.letter, t.letter, t.type, s.id, t.id, 0
FROM data s 
    JOIN map 
        ON s.id = r 
    JOIN data t 
        ON t.id = l
WHERE s.letter = 'BB'
UNION ALL
SELECT my_list.origin, s.letter, t.letter, t.type, s.id, t.id, level + 1 
    FROM data s 
    JOIN map 
        ON (s.id = l OR s.id = r)
JOIN data t 
        ON (t.id = l OR t.id = r) 
    JOIN my_list 
        ON s.id = my_list.tid
WHERE t.id <> s.id 
      AND s.type <> 'END' 
      AND t.id <> my_list.sid
)
SELECT * FROM my_list
WHERE origin = 'BB' AND target_type = 'END'
ORDER BY level
```

Does that improve performance?

Comment: Yes, pushing the predicate into the root selection is probably the best first step.

Comment: No sorry, 'BB' was just an example, the CTE must capable to return for all different letters.

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment. BB can be replaced with any literal inside CTE as well as outside of CTE